# how to get timestamp by date and format in PHP

Tags: php, date, format, timestamp

How to get timestamp by Date & Date Format?

$date = "2014-08-21";
$format = "Y-m-d";

$timestamp = get_timestamp ($date,$format);

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-create-from-format.php

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert one date format into another in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167916/convert-one-date-format-into-another-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As simple as this:

```
$date = "2014-08-21"; $format = "Y-m-d";
$timestamp = \DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $date)->format('U');
```

Addition based on the comment below...

For PHP older thatn 5.3 the following code can be used:

```
$timestamp = strtotime($date);
```

In this case you should make sure that your date format [is one of the supported formats](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php). In your example it is "Year, month and day with dashes" so it should work.

Comment: my php is 5.2 ,  DateTime::createFromFormat PHP>=5.3